# Why do hashCode & equal need non-static fields to be generated?

Tags: eclipse, static

I am curious about this Error I get while testing out Eclipses' functionality:

[image]

I tried to use the command "generate hashCode & Equals", but because the class only has `static` methods it rejected it. How does this work(i.e. `hashCode()`/`equals()` needing non-static methods ? )?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hashCode` and `equals` methods are belonging to a concrete object and need members belonging to the object to compute any meaningful value.

Eg. if you want to compare two instances of the same class, you do that by comparing their "computed values" through their `equals` and/or `hashCode` methods.

Static methods and members belong to the class and not to the concrete instance uniquely.

Comment: also don't use `transient` variable in hashcode() and equals().

Answer (score 2):

hashCode is supposed to generate a unique identifier for each instance of the class and equals compares this instance to another instance to see if they are equal or not. By definition, these methods are necessary for each instance of this class, so the method cannot be static. Also, these methods are inherited from Object as non-static methods and you cannot change that.